# Installing Android Studio app on Iphone for testing

Tags: android, iphone, jailbreak

Is there a way I can install Android on an iPhone for testing purposes? If so, could I move my app from Android Studio to my iPhone then? I was looking at Andrios which is on Cydia (for Jailbroken iPhones)

Answer (score 0):

I was about to comment a NO for an answer but I first made a google search and [I found this](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_install_android_your_ios_devices)

First of all theres no way to do this without jailbreak, that link is for "iDroid" you should thy it.

The thing is I think the computer will not recognize the "android" device, that its actually an iphone, you must sign your app and login with an email acoount in the iphonedroid and then send the apk to that email and install it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my iPhone is a 4S so not compatible with that. I was looking at Andrios tool on Cydia which is prolly better. It costs money so I was wondering if anyone has done this and moved Android apps over to this

Comment: Bob why dont you try GenyMotion? Its far the best android emulator and it might be the best option for you...

Answer (score 0):

you can install an Android app on your iphone by using  [alien dalvik](http://www.technonutty.com/2015/06/how-to-download-run-android-apps-on-ios.html)  or else using this [apple hacks](http://www.applehacks.com) with this you can make your Iphone dual boot.
For installation follow the procedure mentioned in the link given.